# Why apache-hudi is creating COPY_ON_WRITE table even if I have given MERGE_ON_READ?

Tags: pyspark, apache-hudi

I am trying to create a simple hudi table with **MERGE_ON_READ** table type.
After executing the code still in *hoodie.properties* file I see **hoodie.table.type=COPY_ON_WRITE**

Am I missing something here ?

**Jupyter Notebook for this code:** https://github.com/sannidhiteredesai/spark/blob/master/hudi_acct.ipynb

```
hudi_options = {
    "hoodie.table.name": "hudi_acct",
    "hoodie.table.type": "MERGE_ON_READ",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.operation": "upsert",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": "acctid",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": "ts",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field": "date",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning": "true",
    "hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism": 8,
    "hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism": 8,
}

input_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (100, "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:39.340396Z", 10),
        (101, "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T12:14:58.597216Z", 10),
        (102, "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.417052Z", 10),
        (103, "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.519832Z", 10),
        (104, "2015-01-02", "2015-01-01T12:15:00.512679Z", 10),
        (104, "2015-01-02", "2015-01-01T12:15:00.512679Z", 10),
        (104, "2015-01-02", "2015-01-02T12:15:00.512679Z", 20),
        (105, "2015-01-02", "2015-01-01T13:51:42.248818Z", 10),
    ],
    ("acctid", "date", "ts", "deposit"),
)

# INSERT
(
    input_df.write.format("org.apache.hudi")
    .options(**hudi_options)
    .mode("append")
    .save(hudi_dataset)
)


update_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:39.340396Z", 20)],
    ("acctid", "date", "ts", "deposit"))

# UPDATE
(
    update_df.write.format("org.apache.hudi")
    .options(**hudi_options)
    .mode("append")
    .save(hudi_dataset)
)
```

**Edit:** After execution of above code I see 2 parquet files created in the date=2015-01-01 partition. On reading the 2nd parquet file I was expecting to get only the updated 1 record, but I can see all other records in that partition as well.

Comment: Please let me know if the following answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `"hoodie.table.type": "MERGE_ON_READ",` configuration. You have to use `hoodie.datasource.write.table.type` instead. If you update the configuration as  follows it will work. I have tested.

```
hudi_options = {
    "hoodie.table.name": "hudi_acct",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.table.type": "MERGE_ON_WRITE",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.operation": "upsert",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": "acctid",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": "ts",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field": "date",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning": "true",
    "hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism": 8,
    "hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism": 8,
    "hoodie.compact.inline": "true",
    "hoodie.compact.inline.max.delta.commits": 10
}
```

Comment: MERGE_ON_WRITE - mistake

Answer (score 0):

would you please try mode("overwrite") when using insert to load data into hudi first and see if it works?

Comment: I tried with overwrite mode still it is showing same results as COPY ON READ..... Is it something related to my input data size ? Because input data as well as updated data is very small does hudi use COPY_ON_WRITE by default ?

Comment: https://github.com/sannidhiteredesai/spark/blob/master/hudi_acct.ipynb

Comment: no, it should not be related to you data size. does table name correct in hoodie.properties?

Comment: Yes table name is correct. This is in hoodie.properties

hoodie.table.precombine.field=ts
hoodie.table.name=hudi_acct
hoodie.archivelog.folder=archived
hoodie.table.type=COPY_ON_WRITE
hoodie.table.version=1
hoodie.timeline.layout.version=1